# How to get select the li tag before last li tag

Tags: jquery, list

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>

    <script>$("ul li:nth-child(3)").append("<span> - Selected!</span>");</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to select li number 3 and with `:nth-child(3)` but the problem is that the li tag are random sometime it can be 6 or 9 or 20 .. so how to get the last and maybe then use prev() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.eq` accepts negative indices, which count from the end. Note that `.eq` counts on the *set*, not the actual child index. In your case however, the set only consists of the children of the one `ul`, so that doesn't make a difference.

```
$("ul li").eq(-2);  // -1 is last, -2 is one before last
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:nth-last-child` selector:

```
$("ul li:nth-last-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("ul li:last").prev("li").append("<span> - Selected!</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.last()` method or `:last` selector:

```
$('ul li:last').append("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('ul li:last').prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but some time it is useful the have the list of selected elements:

```
var liList = $('#testUl li');
var value = $(liList[liList.length-2]).text();
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sx6sQ/